# Regular Expression: Find html tags which have an attribute twice?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to find any tags which have an attributed declared twice?  More specifically, I'm wanting to scan through html documents and look for any markup which has class="" twice.

So something akin to:

```
<textarea class='something' id='nomatter' name='nomatter' class='different'>
```

Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: What language do you use? And what do you want to do with this attribute after?

Comment: Using Netbeans to edit php/ html files.  I'm just looking to find the double classes for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
<\w+(?:[^>]*?\sclass\s*=){2}[^>]+>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on the context you're using regex in. Are you in a text editor, or PHP, or something else?

Also, are you just finding to adjust them manually or is there replacing involved?

Some regex engines allow you to use a captured group within the search string.

You might do something like this, just to find them:

```
<.+?\s([a-zA-Z]+?)='[a-zA-z-]+?'.*?\s\1='[a-zA-Z-]+?'.*?>
```

That `\1` in there is referencing the first (and only) captured group in the parentheses near the beginning.

http://regex101.com/r/gH1uJ4

On an unrelated note, I think it's weird that you are using single quotes in your HTML attributes.

Comment: Yes, using Netbeans to edit php / html. Your solution didnt work there, I'm guessing it's releated to it now being able to use a captured group?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "<textarea class='something' id='nomatter' name='nomatter' class='different'>";
my @matches = ($string =~ m/<.+?class='([a-zA-Z]+?)'.*class='([a-zA-Z-]+?)'/g);
if ( scalar @matches > 1 ) { print "There is two class attributes in this line!\n"; }
```